# Plot multiple vegas charts in the same window

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, vegas-viz

I am using vegas on IntelliJ to plot charts from Spark dataframes.

Since I am not using a notebook like Jupyter with Toree, my charts are displayed on separate windows, which is quite annoying when I have to plot 20 of them.

I would like to know if there is a way to make a subplot like in Matplotlib in python. Should I definitely use a notebook instead?

Here is my code in Scala, where `histogram` is a dataframe with 2 columns : `cube` and `count`:

```
Vegas("Histogram").
    withDataFrame(histogram).
    encodeX("cube", Quantitative, scale = Scale(ScaleType.Log), title = "cube " + name).
    encodeY("count", Quantitative).
    mark(Bar).
    show
```

Answer (score 0):

//Following is what I did in my use case, for your reference only
Vegas.layered("linear regression",width=600, height=300).
          withLayers(
          Layer().
          withDataFrame(df).
          mark(Point).
          encodeX("features", Quantitative).
          encodeY("label", Quantitative),
          Layer().
          withDataFrame(df_pred).
         mark(Line).
          encodeX("features", Quantitative).
          encodeY("prediction", Quantitative)
          ).
          show

Following is the output, that has scatter plot and straight line in the same chart windows.

[Scatter and line are on the same chart window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQhtH.jpg)

Comment: It's been more than one year so I don't bother searching for too long (it may be a good question for another future user though). I was looking for a solution to display charts side by side [like this example with matplotlib in python](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_star_poly.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-star-poly-py), more than plotting several curves on the same chart.